# PagedList didn't render properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

I installed `PagedList` and `PagedList.Mvc` packages via `NuGet`. Then I used it in the manner:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@model IPagedList<Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListEmployees";
}

<h3>All Employees (@ViewBag.TotalEmployees)</h3>

@if(Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Employee.Card", item);
    }

    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("List", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.Minimal)
}
else
{
    @: no records were found. Sorry
}
```

with the code inside controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<Employee> repository; 
    private Int32 PageSize = 10;

    public EmployeeController(IRepository<Employee> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult List(Int32? page)
    {
        var set = repository.Get();
        ViewBag.TotalEmployees = set.Count();

        return View(set.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize));
    }
}
```

Is this normal to have unstyled unordered list as a result. And how then I apply my custom styling to the pager?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

creator of the PagedList nuget package here.

To be honest, I'm not sure what is going on - it strikes me as quite odd. My best guess based upon the description you gave is that `Url.Action("List", new {page = page})` is returning a null or empty value which is then causing the `href` attribute to not render. You could test this by adding the following code elsewhere in your view and making sure it returns a real URL:

`<p>@Url.Action("List", new {page = 1})</p>`

If that paragraph tag is empty, then the problem is most likely in your routing.

Comment: Ok. I had only one page so the `next/prev` links were disabled. Think that's the culprit? But what I'm gaining now is plain unordred list with no styling. Is that normal behavior and should I apply my styles?

Comment: that is normal behavior if you haven't included the pagedlist.css file (or styled it yourself)

Comment: @Troy, setting the value of page to 1 did it for me. Thanks!